# How To Read and Write Records In SQLite Using SQLite Net Extensions?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

Here is the documentation I've looked at and may be helpful: [Sample SQLite OneToMany Unit Test](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/Tests/IntegrationTests/Tests/OneToManyTests.cs) and [General Read and Write Documentation in Readme](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/readme.md)

My use-case is that I've already inserted an `Item` and I am now editing an `Item`. So I will need to basically update the `Item` record and insert n `ItemPhoto` records. Basically, I'mtalking about the case of `SaveItem(..)` where `Item.Id != 0`.

It seems that when I step through the code to write to the database I am seeing all of the keys being assigned to the objects in memory appropriately. However, later when I go to read an `Item` by calling `GetWithChildren(..)` in every case except one the `ItemPhotos` property has a Count of 0. The only time that `ItemPhotos` actually gets populated is the case when the `ItemPhotoId` is 0. My best guess is that somehow the `ItemPhotoId` is not being set before `GetWithChildren(..)` is run and then it only works when the default in-memory value of 0 actually matches the database's `ItemPhotoId` for the given Item.

Here is my code showing the models and the read and write code:

```
public class Item
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<ItemPhoto> ItemPhotos { get; set; }
}

public class ItemPhoto
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ItemPhotoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Item))]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public string FileLocation { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]      // Many to one relationship with Item
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

class SqlLiteDataStore
{
    static SQLiteConnection Database;

    ...

    public Item GetItem(int id)
    {
        return Database.GetWithChildren<Item>(id, true);
    }

    public Item SaveItem(Item item)
    {
        // Simpler Attempt #1
        // Database.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(item);
        // return item;

        // Manual Attempt #2
        if (item.Id != 0)
        {
            foreach (var photo in item.ItemPhotos)
            {
                if (photo.ItemPhotoId == 0)
                    Database.Insert(photo);
            }
            Database.UpdateWithChildren(item);

            return item;
        }
        else
        {
            Database.InsertWithChildren(item, true);
            return item;
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I fixed it by dropping the existing tables and recreating them and beforehand just renaming the `ItemPhoto`'s `ItemPhotoId` property to `Id`. Maybe the library assumes the primary key name of `Id` or maybe I changed something else along the way in terms of the models that just needed the tables to be recreated instead of migrated? Also, the simpler attempt at saving with just the `Database.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(item);` seems to work just fine so I'm going with that for what it's worth.